# Is any solution to make interactive TCP/UDP server under Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, udp

I need some tool like [this one](https://tcp-test-tool.apponic.com/) (called "TCP Test Tool") for Linux. I need not a GUI (i.e. GUI/CLI -- this is not so important), but I need to be able to make a server which can listen at any port, receive **and** send a raw (i.e. a *hex dump*) data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There](https://pastebin.com/89Q61FFw) is a patch for socat v.2.0.0.b8 which makes it possible.

Answer (score 5):

try `nc`

from `man nc`

> **nc** — arbitrary TCP and UDP connections and listens

Comment: I know about it. But how can I to receive **and** send a **raw** (hex) data interactively? I.e. I need to start a server, then send some data to it (using nc or other soft), see what was received and send a (raw) answer back. May you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2):

**socat** is a sophisticated tool to connect, bidirectionally, almost anything to almost anything else.  In particular, you can get it to listen on a port
for connections, run a program when connected, send the data to it, and
return output back to the socket. Eg:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:3344,reuseaddr,fork  EXEC:/tmp/runme,pty
```

will run a script `/tmp/runme` eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo sigterm >&2;exit' TERM
echo "start" >&2
while read line
do  echo "got $line"
done
```

in which you can do what you like with the data, such as here
returning it with the prefix "got ". You can test this with, eg, `telnet localhost 3344` or

```
echo hi | socat - TCP4:localhost:3344
```

If you need to do the same with udp you can instead try, eg:

```
socat UDP-RECVFROM:3344,fork  EXEC:/tmp/runme,pty
```

you will only be passed one packet, but you still get any reply. 
Test it with, eg:

```
echo hi | socat - UDP-SENDTO:localhost:3344
```

If all you want to do is get your data echoed back, this feature is built into `xinetd`, and you only need enable the *echo* service. See `man xinetd.conf`.

If you want to get bandwidth statistics, look at the [netperf](http://www.netperf.org/svn/netperf2/tags/netperf-2.7.0/doc/netperf.html#The-Design-of-Netperf) tool.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I wrote my question unclearly. I bypassed that I want to get a _hex_ dump and to type a _hex_ and send corresponding binary data back. So, I investigated the socat a little in a last days and it seems it is a good stuff for my issue, but it have not a hex i/o. So it needs an external tool/script to do this conversion. Maybe could you suggest it?

Comment: You can pipe the raw data into `xxd -p` to get long lines of hex, and for the reverse pipe into `xxd -r -p` to convert hex lines into data.

Comment: I know about it too, but it waits the eof so it is inconvenient for my task. I think there's need to write a little script or a program in C.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in `sendip`, its website: http://snad.ncsl.nist.gov/ipv6/sendip.html

From the site:

> **Q: How are string and numeric arguments handled?** A: Many of the header fields, and the packet data area, can be specified via the following syntax:
>
> - 0xXXXX - interpreted as a number in hex, converted to a binary number in network byte order.
> - 0XXXX - interpreted as a number in octal, converted to a binary number in network byte order.
> - rN - N "random" bytes
> - zN - N nul (zero) bytes
> - fF - read the argument from the next line in file F
> - other - taken as a literal string

Comment: May be, but as far as I understood sendip can not be a server.